# Class inheritance - Calling properties and/or methods not in the parent class

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to understand class inheritance.

Suppose I have the following code (PHP):

```
class A {
     public function fire() {
        echo "Fire!";
     } 
}

class B extends A {
     public function water() {
        echo "Water!";
     }
}

class C extends B {
     public function lightning() {
         echo "Lightning!";
     }
}

$cObject = new C();

$cObject->fire();
```

My questions are

- Even though the fire() method is not defined in class C nor class B, $cObject->fire() works.  Does class C inherit not only class B's methods, but class A's methods?  I'm trying to find out how many levels deep inheritance will go.
- Is there a term for calling a property or method that does not exist in the current object instance, but this property or method exists in a parent or ancestor class?  EDIT: In other words, fire() is not defined in class C, but $cObject can still call fire().  Is there any particular term/jargon for this concept?  (Or is it just part of the definition of "class inheritance")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Class 'B' is an 'A'.  Class 'C' is a 'B', therefor, 'C' is an 'A'.  Everything that 'B' has rights and privileges to in 'A', 'C' has as well.  C++ has a concept of private inheritance that gets a little funky here, but that's the general idea.  As said in the other answer, inheritance will go as far as the chain is defined.

2) I think you meant to ask "What is a function called that is *not defined in derived class, but instead in the base class.*  This type of function is called a virtual function.  From what I understand, every class function in PHP is a virtual function and can be overridden (reimplemented in a derived class) unless it is declared as *final*.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, for question #2, that is the term I was looking for.

Comment: Could you give a link to that *virtual* function thing?

Comment: This appears to be a good primer: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to find out how many levels deep inheritance will go.

infinetely, if you want. no limits

> Is there a term for calling a property or method that does not exist in the current object instance, but this property or method exists in a parent or ancestor class?

For class variables: `no`.
For class methods: `yes`. declare them as `private`:

```
class A {
    private function test() {
        echo 'test';
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->test();
    }
}

$b = new B();
```

Output:

```
Fatal error: Call to private method A::test() from context 'B' in /home/thorsten/a.php on line 14
```

Comment: With my second question, I mean to say, "I'm calling fire() from $cObject, but fire() is not defined in class C.  What is this concept called?  Is there a jargon/term that is used for this"

Comment: @hek2mgl
"For class variables: no."  is wrong.
class variables have the same visibilty modifiers as the methods.
If you mark a property private in the parent class it is not inherit by the child class.
Only public and protected properties are accessible from the child class scope.
One special case to mention: readonly properties which are introduced with PHP 8.1 are  only setable in the class they are defined.
So in this case you need to add a __construct method in the parent class and explicitly call it from the __construct method of the child class by parent::__construct.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderBehling. This answer is old and I haven't worked with PHP since a while, especially never with php7. At the time I wrote the answer, it was PHP-5.2 or 5.3. ... It seems the behavior has changed since then? Feel free to edit the answer

Comment: I see. Haven't overlooked it.
Thanks for pointing this out.

Indeed modifiers for class properties was not available in PHP 5.
PHP 5 was the first version on which OOP was introduce and its concept was very limited and missed a lot of OOP core concepts such as encapsulation.
With PHP 7 OOP get a huge boost. Encapsulation was now supported, which fixed security issues.
With PHP 8 it was improve even further with other useful things such as enums.
As a positive side effect the overall performance becomes better and better with each version.

Comment: Good to hear :) Thank you!